# How to join in SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to learn `SQL-SERVER` and I have created the below query:

```
WITH T AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.DIALOG_ID) as row_num, *
    FROM test.db as d
    INNER JOIN test.dbs as ds
    ON d.DIALOG_ID = ds.DIALOG_ID 
)
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE row_num <=10;
```

I found that the only way to limit is with `ROW_NUMBER()`.
Although when I try to run the join I have this error:

> org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [8156] [S0001]: The column 'DIALOG_ID' was specified multiple times for 'T'.

Comment: The error *is* telling you the problem here. Define the columns you need, don't use `*`. Your CTE `T` has the column `DIALOG_ID` twice, and you can't have columns with the same alias. Once from the table `test.db` and the other from the table `test.dbs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem: In the `WITH`, you do `SELECT *` which gets all columns from both tables `db` and `dbs`. Both have a column `DIALOG_ID`, so a column by that name ends up **twice** in the result set of the WITH.

Although until here that is all allowed, it is not good practice: why have the same data twice?

Things go wrong when SQL Server has to determine what `SELECT * FROM T` means: it expands SELECT * to the actual columns of T, but it finds a duplicate column name, and then it refuses to continue.

The fix (and also highly recommended in general): **be specific about the columns that you want to output**. If `T` has no duplicate columns, then `SELECT * FROM T` will succeed.

Note that the even-more-pure variant is to also be specific about what columns you select from T. By doing that it becomes clear at a glance what the SELECT produces, instead of having to guess or investigate when you look at the query later on (or when someone else does).

The updated code would look like this (fill in your column names as we don't know them):

```
WITH T AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.DIALOG_ID) as row_num,
        d.DIALOG_ID, d.SOME_OTHER_COL,
        ds.DS_ID, ds.SOME_OTHER_COL_2
    FROM test.db AS d
    INNER JOIN test.dbs AS ds ON d.DIALOG_ID = ds.DIALOG_ID 
)
SELECT row_num, DIALOG_ID, SOME_OTHER_COL, DS_ID, SOME_OTHER_COL_2
FROM T
WHERE row_num <= 10;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. It is very helpful. I want to ask something more. I did your approach with two columns dialog_id and steps. dialog_id has the same value but steps is not . I want to distinct(have different values) in dialog id not in steps.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Also, for followup questions, it is better to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH T AS
 (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.DIALOG_ID) as row_num, d.*
    FROM test.db as d
    INNER JOIN test.dbs as ds
    ON d.DIALOG_ID = ds.DIALOG_ID 
 )
SELECT *
FROM T
  WHERE row_num <=10;
```

Comment: This will return only the columns from d table right?  I want columns from both

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you need columns from both, I would suggest give them names in the cte,e.g. d.column1,d.column2...,ds.column1 and  pay special attention to the column DIALOG_ID.I mean write d.DIALOG_ID as d_DIALOG_ID, ds.DIALOG_ID as ds_dialog_id

Comment: Also, I saw that the results are duplicated. How can I distinct them ?

Comment: I would suggest you add sample data and desired output to the question. It would be the best way. The simplest - try to use DISTINCT,but carefully check results